# html2canvas does not print jsPlumb Connectors

Tags: svg, jsplumb, html2canvas

How to print SVG elements that are built by jsPlumb.

Known that getting all SVG Elements drawen by jsPlumb is retrieved by this code :

```
var uiJsPlumbConnectors=jsPlumb.getAllConnections().map(function(conn){return conn.canvas;})
```

All connectors are SVG elements :

Using `html2canvas` to print all connectors (SVG), it does not work :

```
html2canvas(uiJsPlumbConnectors).then(function(c){

     window.open(c.toDataURL('image/png'))

});
```

An image has been generated , however, it is an emply image .

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/gXuS7/563/)

### It seems that `html2canvas` does not support yet multi-elements drawing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I checked html2canvas was not able to convert SVGs, you will need another script to handle that.

The steps:

- transfer html elements to canvas
- transfer svg elements to canvas
- export canvas

I used https://code.google.com/p/canvg/ to export to the same canvas after using html2canvas. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this

```
<%--stuff for printing--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../Scripts/Print/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="<%=AdminPath%>Scripts/canvg/rgbcolor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=AdminPath%>Scripts/canvg/StackBlur.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=AdminPath%>Scripts/canvg/canvg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> jsplumb div

```
<div class="demo statemachine-demo" id="statemachine-demo" style="margin: 0px;">
            </div>
```

> hidden div for printing

```
            <div id="canvasDiv" style='visibility:hidden;' >
            </div>


function renderImage()
{
    var statemachinediv = document.getElementById('statemachine-demo'); 

    html2canvas([statemachinediv], {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {

            document.getElementById('canvasDiv').appendChild(canvas);
            var svgList = $(statemachinediv).find( "svg" );

            svgList.each(function(index, value) { 

                try 
                {
                    var svgExample = this; 

                    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                    var svgMarkup = serializer.serializeToString(svgExample);

                    if(svgMarkup.indexOf("_jsPlumb_connector") > -1)
                    {
                        var leftIndex = svgMarkup.indexOf("left: "); 
                        var endOfLeft = svgMarkup.indexOf("px", leftIndex);
                        var leftPosition = svgMarkup.substring(leftIndex+6, endOfLeft );
                        var left = parseInt(leftPosition); 

                        var topIndex = svgMarkup.indexOf("top: "); 
                        var endOfTop = svgMarkup.indexOf("px", topIndex);
                        var topPosition = svgMarkup.substring(topIndex+5, endOfTop );
                        var top = parseInt(topPosition); 

                        svgMarkup = svgMarkup.replace('xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"',''); 

                        var connectorCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvg(connectorCanvas, svgMarkup); //add connector to canvas

                        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        context.drawImage(connectorCanvas, left, top);
                    }
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    showBalloon('error in print'); 
                }
            });


            var stateMachineName =     $("#stateMachineDropDown option:selected").text();

            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

            var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');

            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + stateMachineName + '</title>');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body ><table><tr><td>');
            mywindow.document.write('</td></tr></table><img src="' + data + '" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.print();




        }
    });

    return false; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a old question, but, this helped me. [Mode details.](http://eatandcode.es/2017/08/12/Soluciones-a-la-captura-de-svg-con-html2canvas/)

```
$clone.find('.jtk-connector').each(function () {
      // for every SVG element created by JsPlumb for connections...
      var left = parseInt(this.style.left, 10) + 'px';
      var top = parseInt(this.style.top, 10) + 'px';
      this.removeAttribute('style');
      this.removeAttribute('position');
      this.setAttribute('width', parseInt(this.getAttribute('width'), 10)  + 'px');
      this.setAttribute('height', parseInt(this.getAttribute('height'), 10) + 'px');
      this.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');
      this.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
      // this.children[0] is the path for connection line
      // this.children[1] is the path for connection arrow shape
      this.children[0].setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'); 
      this.children[1].setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
      this.setAttribute('viewbox', '0 0 ' + parseInt(this.getAttribute('width'), 10) + ' ' + parseInt(this.getAttribute('height'), 10));
      this.children[0].setAttribute('stroke-width', '2px');
      this.children[0].setAttribute('stroke', '#c9c9c9');
      this.children[1].setAttribute('fill', '#c9c9c9');
      this.children[1].setAttribute('stroke', '#c9c9c9');
      $clone.find(this).wrap('<span style="position: absolute; left: ' + left + '; top: ' + top + ';"></span>');
    });
```